# How the hell does regex work? Professor didn't explain at all

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex filter. Here are the parameters:

- 11 chars
- First char is uppercase A-M
- Second char is uppercase A-L
- Chars 3-10 (next 8 chars) are numbers, but it can't be all 0s (i.e 00000000 is bad but 00001000) is fine
- Last char is uppercase A-Z but but can't be letter Z or letter O

I've gotten to here:

```
^[A-M]{1}[A-L]{1}\d{8}[A-Y^O]{1}
```

Which matches everything but doesn't exclude 8 zeros from the digits or O from the last character.

Any help is greatly appreciated; professor did an absimal job of explaining regex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern to ensure that there is at least one non-zero digit, and use two ranges instead of one to skip the letter `O` in the character set:

```
^[A-M][A-L](?=.*[1-9])\d{8}[A-NP-Y]$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5eivNv/1

Comment: Oh, brilliant. So you're saying, capture all of the digits, as long as they contain a 1-9; I love this solution, thank you so much!

Comment: I also added a quantifier to lock the number of digits at 8; thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another variant could be asserting not 8 times a zero using a negative lookahead `(?!0{8})`  and then match 8 digits.

Note that you can omit the `{1}` from the pattern.

```
^[A-M][A-L](?!0{8})\d{8}[A-NP-Y]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c8xFGB/1)

Comment: Awesome! Your solution is easier to understand as it has been done exactly in the way the requirement has been specified - `Chars 3-10 (next 8 chars) are numbers, but it can't be all 0s`.